# Problems extracting Zip in Java

Tags: java, zip, extract, subdirectory

I have been trying to good java to extract a few zip files in my program and place them in their correct directories. I have been looking off of this for reference : 
http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/code-base/how-to-extract-zip-file-with-subdirectories/

My current code looks like

```
                String ziplocation = "/home/user/folder/";
                String zipfile = "libraries.zip";
                String liblocation = "/home/user/folder";

                ZipEntry zipentry;

                if (!zipentry.isDirectory())
                {
                    File fileFile = new File(liblocation + "/" + zipentry.getName());

                    InputStream inputstream = zipfile.getInputStream(zipentry);
                    String str = new java.util.Scanner(inputstream).useDelimiter("/A").next();

                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileFile));
                    bw.append(str);
                    bw.close();

                }
```

Everything seems to be correctly adapted from that above reference but when I compile it gives me :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method getInputStream(ZipEntry) is undefined for the type String

at Main.main(Main.java:53)
```

EDIT:

I have now changed it to

```
                String ziplocation = "/home/user/folder/zipfile.zip";
                String liblocation = "/home/user/folder/";

                File file = new File(ziplocation);
                ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(file);
                InputStream inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(zipfile));

                ZipEntry zipentry;

                if (!zipentry.isDirectory())
                {
                    File fileFile = new File(liblocation + "/" + zipentry.getName());

                    InputStream inputstream = zipfile.getInputStream(zipentry);
                    String str = new java.util.Scanner(inputstream).useDelimiter("/A").next();

                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileFile));
                    bw.append(str);
                    bw.close();

                }
```

But now the compiler is responding with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from BufferedReader to InputStream
The constructor FileReader(ZipFile) is undefined

at Main.main(Main.java:48)
```

Comment: In mentioned article `zipfile` is `ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(file);`. In your code it is `String zipfile = "libraries.zip";`. As your error massage says: "*The method `getInputStream(ZipEntry)` is undefined for the type `String`*"

Comment: Pshemo, why not make an answer out of it?

Answer (score 0):

It means that a string object doesn't have a getInputStream method. In this line:
zipfile.getInputStream(zipentry);

zipfile is a string.

You need something like
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(zipfile));

There's a good discussion of IO streams here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the sentence:

```
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(zipfile));
```

That sentence is not in the example that you are following. Instead, there is a loop through the elements found inside ***zipfile***:

```
File file = new File(zipFileLocation);
ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(file);

ZipEntry zipentry;

System.out.println("nList of files in zip archive");
int fileNumber = 0;
for (Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = zipfile.entries(); e
        .hasMoreElements(); fileNumber++) {
    zipentry = e.nextElement();

    if (!zipentry.isDirectory()) {
...
```